# How to define transmissions with ros2 control

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, transmission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my current understanding, if you want to use ROS2 Control with gazebo, you have to use one `ros2_control` tag with type `system` for all joints. (See https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros2_control)

My question now: How do you define your transmissions?

I found this [components_architecture_and_urdf_examples](https://github.com/ros-controls/roadmap/blob/master/design_drafts/components_architecture_and_urdf_examples.md#7-modular-robots-with-separate-communication-to-each-actuator-with-multi-joints-transmission-example---system-component-is-used), but I can't find anything there.

Robot Description:
I have 3 wheels that control the movement of the robot. Each of them has its own actuator. All of them have the same transmission ratio.

I would like to define three `SimpleTansmission`s, but how do I specify the corresponding joints?
All examples I found define the transmission inside of `<ros2_control name="..." type="actuator">` and not `<ros2_control name="..." type="system">`.

The only `system` transmission I could find, looks like this:

```
<transmission name="transmission1">
  <plugin>transmission_interface/SomeComplex2by2Transmission</plugin>
  <param name="joints">{joint1, joint2}</param>
  <param name="output">{output2, output2}</param>
  <param name="joint1_output1">1.5</param>
  <param name="joint1_output2">3.2</param>
  <param name="joint2_output1">3.1</param>
  <param name="joint2_output2">1.4</param>
</transmission>
```

And as far as I know, this is only a prototype. There is no `SomeComplex2by2Transmission` plugin.

Currently, I see two possible solutions:

1. It is somehow possible to use `type="actuator"` with `gazebo_ros2_control`.
2. There is some way to define simple transmissions in a system.
3. I have to write my own transmission plugin.

I would prefer the first option, because this is way easier to maintain with xacro.

Some links:

- ROS2 Control Documentation:
  https://ros-controls.github.io/control.ros.org/getting_started.html#
- ROS2 Control Demo:
  https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos
- Gazebo ROS2 Control Plugin:
  https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros2_control

My current `ros2_control` tag:

```
  <!-- ROS Control for the rims -->
  <ros2_control name="cassiopeia_rim_control" type="system">
    <xacro:if value="$(arg use_sim)">
      <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
      </hardware>
    </xacro:if>
    <xacro:unless value="$(arg use_sim)">
      <hardware>
        <xacro:if value="$(arg use_fake_hardware)">
          <plugin>fake_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
          <param name="fake_sensor_commands">$(arg fake_sensor_commands)</param>
          <param name="state_following_offset">0.0</param>
        </xacro:if>
        <xacro:unless value="$(arg use_fake_hardware)">
          <!-- TODO: If we want this feature, we have to write an
                     hardware controller plugin in C++ for ROS2 Control.
            -->
        </xacro:unless>
      </hardware>
    </xacro:unless>

    <joint name="a_rim_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-1</param>
        <param name="max">1</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="b_rim_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-1</param>
        <param name="max">1</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="c_rim_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-1</param>
        <param name="max">1</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
  </ros2_control>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
      <parameters>$(find pkg_name)/config/controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385004/how-to-define-transmissions-with-ros2-control/) by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2021-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The support for transmission has [just landed](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/pull/633) in ros2_control. At least the [test case with `SimpleTransmission`](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/blob/8b23233c509d5e79d8579e39af286b48244e3d3e/transmission_interface/test/simple_transmission_loader_test.cpp#L170) is working. I hope this is what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2022-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1